# Process.Start(variável) para abrir uma aplicação sem saber o local de instalação

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho um Console Application que precisa chamar uma aplicação.

Como não vou ter certeza onde foi instalada, preciso atribuir o valor a variável path conforme abaixo para que obtenha o local de instalação da applicação.

```
string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe";
```

Agora quando passo o parâmetro para abrir a aplicação, o Console Application não abre a aplicação.

```
Processe.Start (path);
```

Não é apresentada nenhuma mensagem de erro. Só não carrega o executável.

Como chamar essa applicação quando não sei onde o executável foi instalado?

Comment: Como fica o `path` resultante?

Comment: O recomendável é que se concatene caminhos usando `Path.Combine` assim: `Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe")`

Comment: Eles está dentro de um bloco try catch, porque se não tiver vai dar um erro de `O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado`. Para chamar isso você tem que passar o caminho real da aplicação, ou então, adicionar o `path` nas variáveis de ambiente do windows, porque, se você digitar assim `Processe.Start ("calc.exe")` ele vai abrir a calculadora diferente do seu sistema porque ele não conhece o caminho... O `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` é referente ao caminho de execução do seu aplicativo console, e ai não deve ter o executavel que você procura

Answer (score 1):

Se queres lançar a aplicação a partir de uma localização específica, então tens de saber onde ela está.

Recomendo que não coloques essa localização no teu código mas sim que uses um ficheiro de configuração. Por exemplo, usa [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff648158.aspx).

Mas se a localização da aplicação está na variável de ambiente `PATH`, então é tão simples como isto:

```
Processe.Start("IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe");
```

Comment: Criei uma variável string e passei para ela o seguinte valor: String caminho = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe"); quando chamo essa variável: Process.Start(caminho); o executável não é carregado. Obrigado

Comment: E o executável existe nesse caminho? Alguma exceção é lançada?

Comment: Sim. Criei dois projetos na mesma solution. Criei também um instalador com o inno setup para a aplicação. No diretório de instalação estão os arquivos de ambos projetos. Se coloco o endereço  completo do executável, funciona, porem se utilizo o Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe"); não funciona.

Comment: Se colocas um caminho complete tem de ser o caminho certo, obviamente. Quando instalas a aplicação podias acrescentar o caminho de execução à variável de ambiente PATH.

Comment: Mesmo acrescentando o caminho a PATH não funcionou. Creio que preciso carregar o executável por algum outro comando. Teria algum outro comando em c# console application que carrega aplicações?

Comment: Se executares esta instrução `var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")` imediatamente antes de `Processe.Start("IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe")`, `path` contem o caminho para o executável?

Comment: Nesse exemplo eu preciso passar o endereço de instalação e isso eu não tenho pois o instalador pode alterar o diretório de instalação.